# Change start of the week to Monday

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/building-a-calendar-using-react-js--less-css-and-font-awesome).

It builds a calendar where Sunday is the first day of the week.
I don't completely grok how it works, honestly. What I cannot understand is how to make it show a calendar where week starts from Monday, not Sunday.
I think the problem is somewhere in this line:

```
date = this.state.month.clone().startOf("month").add("w" - 1).day(0),
```

I tried `day(1)`, then it builds weeks starting from Monday, 
 but if the 1st day of the month is Sunday, then it leaves this day on the screen of the previous month, showing the current one starting from the 2nd day:

[image: previous month]
[image: this month]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it.
Instead of trying to get explicit day as start of the week, `startOf('isoWeek')` should be used.
So instead of

```
date = this.state.month.clone().startOf("month").add("w" - 1).day(0),
```

I did:

```
date = this.state.month.clone().startOf("month").add("w"-1).startOf('isoWeek'),
```

and now it looks right:

[image]

Comment: That makes no sense, `"w"-1` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to at least render the current month properly with

```
date = this.state.month.clone().startOf("month").add("w" -1).day(1),
```

as you mentioned, along with rearranging the day of the week labels

```
var DayNames = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div className="week names">
            <span className="day">Mon</span>
            <span className="day">Tue</span>
            <span className="day">Wed</span>
            <span className="day">Thu</span>
            <span className="day">Fri</span>
            <span className="day">Sat</span>
            <span className="day">Sun</span>
            </div>;
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yy33bmze/3/

Comment: I got it to render the same myself as well. Please click to May, 2016 in your code and you'll see the same picture as I posted: there is no May, 2nd.

Comment: @Battle_Slug mentioned trying this, but when the month starts on a Sunday (ie May this year), the calendar starts on the second.